# About the diagonal entries of an inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose that $\bf{A}$ is a full-rank $N \times N$ matrix, ${\bf{a}}_n$ is the $n$-th column of $\bf{A}$ and ${\bf{A}}_n$ is the submatrix obtained by deleting ${\bf{a}}_n$ out of $\bf{A}$.

How to prove
$${\left[ {{{\left( {{\bf{A}}^H{{\bf{A}}}} \right)}^{ - 1}}} \right]_{nn}} = \frac{1}{{{\bf{a}}_n^H{{\bf{a}}_n} - {\bf{a}}_n^H{{\bf{A}}_n}{{\left( {{\bf{A}}_n^H{{\bf{A}}_n}} \right)}^{ - 1}}{\bf{A}}_n^H{{\bf{a}}_n}}}$$
where ${\left(  \cdot  \right)^H}$ stands for Hermitian transpose, ${\left[  \cdot  \right]_{nn}}$ denotes the $n$-th diagonal element.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
\begin{align}
A=\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    A_n & a_n \\
  \end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
A^TA=\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    A_n^TA_n & A_n^Ta_n \\
   a_n^TA_n & a_n^Ta_n
  \end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
Now applying the formula of the inverse of block matrices (see wiki or the paper "Inverses of 2 x 2 Block Matrices" by TzoN-TZER Lu AND SHENG-HUA Shiou) gives
\begin{align}
(A^TA)^{-1}=\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    * & * \\
   * & \left(a_n^Ta_n-a_n^TA_n(A_n^TA_n)^{-1}A_n^Ta_n\right)^{-1}
  \end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
which answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, we should not restrict $n=N$ in our proof.  Actually, the equation holds for any $n = 1, \ldots, N$. So, how to prove this general case?

Comment: This problem has been solved by using the above mentioned method with a permutation matrix. Thanks, Shiyu.